# Attempting to run SQL Server on Docker for Mac: Event not found

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Have made many attempts to run SQL Server in Docker, but all have been unsuccessful. Here's a copy of the text in my terminal for the last attempt:

> Jennifers-MacBook-Pro:~ ziema26$ sudo docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
>   Password:
>   Using default tag: latest
>   latest: Pulling from microsoft/mssql-server-linux
>   Digest: sha256:6c4a13ade5778251bfba648c21fa7968f02aa5b86a7d8b66be710faf8626b38f
>   Status: Image is up to date for microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
>   Jennifers-MacBook-Pro:~ ziema26$

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<password>" -p   1433:1433 --name mydb2 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

-bash: !: event not found

Answer (score 3):

In the examples found on the mssql-server-linux Dockerhub page, it recommeds using a strong password...with the example `yourStrong(!)Password` . If you try and connect to your container passing in special characters like (, ! or ) you'll have problems. Specifically ! is a special character in bash, which refers to the previous command resulting in that error you're receiving, `-bash: !: event not found`

You'll need to escape these characters, e.g `docker exec -it mssql-container-name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P yourStrong\(\!\)Password` or use single quotes.